# How to find the lunar day for Pitru Paksha Shraddha?

Tags: sraddha, pitru, panchang

If we have the date and time of death, how can we find the specific lunar day to perform Pitru Paksha Shraddha?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many tools for that, for example:

Navigate to https://www.drikpanchang.com/panchang/day-panchang.html => Enter city name => Enter Date

This will give you Thithi of that date.

Comment: Yes, this is what I eventually used. Infact, they have a specific tool just to find Shraddha Tithi here - https://www.drikpanchang.com/utilities/tithi/hindu-shraddha-tithi-calculator.html